Overwriting a string in the memory of another process with go on windows
I've been using Go and the Windows API to overwrite a string in another go program.  Technically my string is a []rune array which I'm using because I was having trouble with plain strings.
(target.go)
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    stringVariable := "i_am_the_value"

    var theRuneVariable []rune = []rune(stringVariable)
    memoryPointer := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&theRuneVariable))
    fmt.Printf("Memory address of 'theRuneVariable': 0x%x\n", memoryPointer)

    for {
        fmt.Println(string(theRuneVariable))
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

When I print out the string's pointer in the target.exe which will have its memory overwritten, I see a value like 0xc00009bf08.  I can view this value in a memory editor (I DLed Cheat Engine yesterday for this purpose) and found that it is a struct consisting of a pointer to string data, and a length.
I can overwrite the string data fine from an external Go program run as administrator (using OpenProcess, WriteProcessMemory, etc.) but I've been having trouble scanning the memory for a matching byte pattern.  It apparently takes too long to search for a pattern match when starting from memory address 0x0 (even though it should just be 1.5mbs of memory to scan according to task manager).
From what I've read online, its proper to find the moduleBaseAddress and begin a scan for a matching string from there.  I've been using Module32FirstW and Module32NextW to get the base address for "target.exe".  I only get a value of 0x880000, which is very small compared to my target address being somewhere over 0xc000000000, so I'm not sure this is the right course, and it yields comparable results to beginning the search from 0x0.
So then I scan the memory regions of the program via VirtualQueryEx, but there are quite a few and it's confusing identifying which one to search.  Is it best to search through all of them?  The code below goes through all the modules, and does some filtering to hopefully arrive at a reasonable starting point.
func inspectMemoryRegions(processHandle syscall.Handle, address uintptr) uintptr {
    for {
        mbi, err := queryMemoryRegion(processHandle, address)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error querying memory region:", err)
            break
        }

        //                       0x007ffe0000
        //                       0xc00009bf08
        // if mbi.BaseAddress == 0xc000000000 {
        if mbi.Type == MEM_PRIVATE && mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect == 0x4 && mbi.RegionSize > 0x80000 {
            fmt.Printf("Memory region found at: 0x%x\n", mbi.BaseAddress)
            fmt.Printf("mbi.State: 0x%x\n", mbi.State)
            fmt.Printf("mbi.Type: 0x%x\n", mbi.Type)
            fmt.Printf("mbi.Protect: 0x%x\n", mbi.Protect)
            fmt.Printf("mbi.RegionSize: 0x%x\n", mbi.RegionSize)
            fmt.Println()
            return mbi.BaseAddress
        }

        // Move to the next region
        address = mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize
        if address == 0 {
            break // End of address space
        }
    }
    return uintptr(0)
}

I can get it to return 0xc000000000 after all of that if stuff, but I'm puzzled what this region of memory is called (data segment? heap? stack?), and whether I can assume that address is a reasonable place to start scanning memory on windows machines.  If it's dynamic across machine/ program launch, is there a more sophisticated way of locating it?

Some thing which may be confusing you: you are printing the address of theRuneVariable slice header, not the actual array of runes. The []rune data is not a string, it is a slice of runes, which are unencoded int32 code points. Any access to that as a string will encode the data elsewhere. The result of []rune(stringVariable), hence theRuneVariable, does not escape to the heap in your example so is only allocated on the stack for the duration of the function.

That, and because the program does not have any synchronization primitives the compiler is free to do as it likes, i.e. evaluate string(theRuneVariable) only once.

Thankyou for sharing these important insights.  Given that the memory region we're seeing the data written to, I figured that a good way to identify the memory region to search would be to pull the ESP/ RSP stack pointer register.  I used OpenThread, SuspendThread, and GetThreadContext from the windows API to dump the register information, however none of the 6 threads I dump have a value very close to what RSP actually is when I open a real debugger and break on memory access; rather than getting 0xc... I get 0xd5c59ff678 for instance.
